# Can I use and expression containing the words from ... and hither?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am currently translating a text from the Greek language containing an expression, from there (name of a place in the Aegean) to this place (here), but I can't seem to find a proper way to phrase that. Can I say from Aegeas hither? My Greek text uses the word "δώθε" which actually means coming this way, till this point.

Comment: Well, if you're going to use a word as archaic as "hither", I guess you might as well use "thence" as well:  "Thence hither."

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the target audience for the work.  Hither does indeed mean "to this place," but it's also archaic.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hither

> **adverb**
>    *archaic* or  *literary*
>
> To or toward this place:  ‘I little knew then that such calamity
>   would summon me hither!’

So if you're translating a scholarly or literary work, then it could be appropriate.  If it's for a general audience, then I would not recommend using it.  Simply "from (name of place) to here" would be better in that case.